# Javascript Pop up not popping up?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, popup

Im currently trying to create a popup that displays when the page loads.

I see the content of the popup, but its just at the top of the page (welcome to my website!) and not actually a new popup window that displays after the page loads. Any ideas why its not working? I tried a variety of suggestions from around stack overflow and website tutorials but nothing seems to work

My html/js stuff:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tooltipster.bundle.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tooltipster-sideTip-punk.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="tooltipster.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function PopUp(){
        document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display="none"; 
}
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
      theme: 'tooltipster-punk',
      'maxWidth': 270, // set max width of tooltip box
      contentAsHTML: true, // set title content to html
      trigger: 'custom', // add custom trigger
       triggerOpen: { // open tooltip when element is clicked, tapped (mobile) or hovered
           click: true,
           tap: true,
           mouseenter: true
           },
          triggerClose: { // close tooltip when element is clicked again, tapped or when the mouse leaves it
           click: true,
           scroll: false, // ensuring that scrolling mobile is not tapping!
           tap: true,
           mouseleave: true
           }
  });
  setTimeout(function(){
      PopUp();
   },5000); // 5000 to load it after 5 seconds from page load
});

</script>
</head>
<body> 
<div id="ac-wrapper">
  <div id="popup">
  <center>
    <h2> welcome to my website! </h2>
  </center>
  </div>
</div> 

(the rest of my html content)
```

This is my style file:

```
....

#ac-wrapper {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
z-index: 1001;
}
#popup{
width: 555px;
height: 375px;
background: #FFFFFF;
border: 5px solid #000;
border-radius: 25px;
-moz-border-radius: 25px;
-webkit-border-radius: 25px;
box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
-moz-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
-webkit-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
position: relative;
top: 150px; left: 375px;
}
```

Comment: See if removing the quotes here `'maxWidth': 270` helps. I don't see why that would be the only object property with quotes.

Comment: can you provide a code snippet demo or codepen link?

Comment: @RobMoll I removed the quotes, but it didnt do anything :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, you flipped the logic by setting the popup to display by default and `Popup()` removes it rather than display it.

```js
function PopUp() {
  // display content by setting display to "block"
  document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#ac-wrapper {
  display: none; // content not displayed by default
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks friend! that worked -- now to figure out how to add an x button :D